# Select an earlier commit message when commiting in EGit in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

In EGit inside Eclipse IDE, I am missing the feature of a "commit message history", ie. being able to select one of the most recent commit messages for a new commit, a feature that I quite often use in CVS/SVN.

I see that in Eclipse IDE preferences at Git > Committing there ist a "Maximum number of commit messages in history". This hints at such a feature being present.

I just could not find/google how to access it? What would that option do otherwise? I also find my recent commits stored in the workspace metadata in a file called `org.eclipse.egit.ui.prefs`.

Please note that this is NOT about viewing the history of commits in the past, and therefore to my knowledge not a duplicate question!

Comment: I would personally just use `git log` from the command line, but follow the duplicate link for an eGit solution.

Comment: One option is to use `git commit -c <commit> --reset-author` from the command line. `-c` or `-C` allows you to reuse the message of that commit. `-c` is editable and `-C` is not.

Comment: In the _Git Staging_ view, in the _Commit Message_ field just hit Ctrl+Space (in contrast to SVN it is a content assist instead of a separate pull-down menu).

Comment: Please note that this is NOT about viewing the history of commits in the past, and therefore to my knowledge not a duplicate question!

Ctrl+Space is the answer I was looking for, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, this is not in any way a duplicate question. Although it says "commit message history", it's about *reusing* (and editing) old commit messages, not about looking at the commit history. EGit provides a specific feature for doing this which isn't terribly ovious.

Comment: what is the mac shortcut?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With the cursor in the "Commit message" box, press `Ctrl+Space` to show a list of previous commit messages. Select one and the "Commit message" box will be populated with that message.

[image: Screenshot showing old commit messages]

Comment: what's the shortcut on a mac??

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, this shortcut may not work for you, it is due to that shortcut is already set for toggling keyboard input source. You must disable that then ctrl+space works

Setting/Preference > Keyboard or Command+space, type "keyboard" press enter

Then, keyboard shortcut button > Input source(on the left)

Disable all of them or just disable the ctrl+space one and now you can use the shortcut to see the previous commit messages